# python urllib add function to headers info

Tags: python, http-headers, urllib

excuse my lack of knowledge but I wasn't able to find a solution to this simple syntax problem.

```
requestHdr = (
            'Host: amazon.com\r\n'
            'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0 Iceweasel/31.4.0\r\n' 
            'Accept: */*\r\n'
            'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5\r\n'
            'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8\r\n'
            'Origin: http://amazon.com\r\n'
            'Pragma: no-cache\r\n'
            'ID: str(uuid.uuid1())[:6]' 
            'Cache-Control: no-cache\r\n\r\n'
            'Connection: Close\r\n')
```

I'm trying to add this function str(uuid.uuid1())[:6] into the headers at 'ID: id number' header like this. but i'm having incorrect syntax issues.

Comment: Could  `<=== function*` be the reason?

Comment: hehe `<=== function*` was there to just show where the function is that needs to be active instead of being a header "value", i removed for clarifications :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to concatenate the strings (merge them together) using a simple `+` operator. You can do that anywhere where you use strings,

```
requestHdr = (
        'Host: amazon.com\r\n'
        'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0 Iceweasel/31.4.0\r\n' 
        'Accept: */*\r\n'
        'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5\r\n'
        'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8\r\n'
        'Origin: http://amazon.com\r\n'
        'Pragma: no-cache\r\n'
        'ID: ' + str(uuid.uuid1())[:6] 
        'Cache-Control: no-cache\r\n\r\n'
        'Connection: Close\r\n')
```

For places where you don't want to use the `+` operator (it can make code look slightly messy), you can use the `str.format` method in the same way, like so:
[`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) is a method that you can use to insert variables into a string anywhere. Just insert `{}` in a string and at the end, use the `.format()` to insert whatever you need to add (as parameters to `format` of course!)

```
requestHdr = (
    'Host: amazon.com\r\n'
    'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0 Iceweasel/31.4.0\r\n' 
    'Accept: */*\r\n'
    'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5\r\n'
    'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8\r\n'
    'Origin: http://amazon.com\r\n'
    'Pragma: no-cache\r\n'
    'ID: {}'.format(str(uuid.uuid1())[:6])
    'Cache-Control: no-cache\r\n\r\n'
    'Connection: Close\r\n')
```

Comment: What's your traceback? I should also point out that you need a comma between every element in the tuple, like this: `(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)`

Comment: Is each item (Host, User-Agemt, Accept...) separate items? You should have commas to make sure that they are separate. Otherwise, it will merge the strings together. I'm assuming that you don't want everything in there to be one single string. `('y' 'o' ' ' 'm' 'y' ' ' 'n' 'a' 'm' 'e' ' ' 'i' 's' ' ' 'z' 'i' 'n')` is equal to 'yo my name is zin`.